# get all row data by ag-grid React Hook code example

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid-react

In React Hook for Ag-Grid:

1. How to create button "Get Row Data"
2. get all row data into an Array after editing?

Get user editing/changes and update the array

Answer (score 1):

You can access the updated value via [cellEditingStopped](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-editing-cellEditingStopped) or [rowEditingStarted](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-editing-rowEditingStarted) if you edited row data. And also you can get the update rowData with `getRowData()` triggered by `onCellEditingStopped` or `onCellEditingStopped`.

```js
const gridRef = useRef<AgGridReact>(null)

function getRowData() {
  let rowData = [];
  gridRef.current.api.forEachNode(node => rowData.push(node.data));
  return rowData;
}

return(
<>
  <button onclick={getRowData}>Get RowData</button>
  <AgGridReact
    ref={gridRef}
    onCellEditingStopped={(event: CellEditingStoppedEvent) => console.log(getRowData())
    }
    onRowEditingStopped={(event: RowEditingStoppedEvent) => console.log(getRowData())
    }
  />
</>
)
```

[Compelete working code](https://plnkr.co/edit/DJEpIm1KIJbqBXsC?preview)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have errors in CellEditingStoppedEvent and RowEditingStoppedEvent)

Comment: Hi jyangca: Thanks for your answer. How to define CellEditingStoppedEvent and RowEditingStoppedEvent?

Comment: "onlick" should be "onClick"? Can you give me the complete working code?

Comment: Complete code here! 
https://plnkr.co/edit/DJEpIm1KIJbqBXsC?preview